# Contrapositive of the Transitive Property of Equality

Tags: logic

My teacher asked us to find the converse, inverse, and contrapositive of the transitive property of equality.

$\text{If }x = y\text{ and }y = z\text{, then }x = z$

My answer is 
$\text{If }x \neq z\text{, then }y \neq z\text{ or }x \neq z$

The teacher's correct answer is 
$\text{If }x \neq z\text{, then }y \neq z\text{ and }x \neq z$

This is what I did:

$$p \land q \implies r$$
$$\neg r \implies \neg (p \land q) $$
$$\neg r \implies \neg p \lor \neg q $$

Comment: You are right and your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Cf. [DeMorgan’s Laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: Neither answer as copied here is correct. In both cases you have "$x \ne z$ in the conclusion. I presume in both cases it is supposed to be $x \ne y$. A statement and its contra-positive are equivalent, but if you let $x=0, y = 0, z = 1$, you can see that the transitivity property is true, but your teacher's supposed contrapositive (after the correction) is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is valid, but there may be a typo in your answer.   Do make sure you have transcribed the positions of the $x,y,z$ correctly.

By contraposition and deMorgan's Law we have that the following are equivalent:
$$p\land q~\to~ r\\[2ex]\lnot r\to \lnot (p \land q)\\[2ex]\lnot r\to\lnot p\lor\lnot q$$

Thus the contrapositive of "If $x=y$ and $y=z$, then $x=z$" is **"If $x\neq z$, then $x\neq y$ or $y\neq z$"**.